# Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException when merging entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm new to spring. recently I've been trying to use spring JPA and hibernate to connect to database and insert data.

I could insert entity into database, but I cant remove them.

I created a main DAO which is abstract and all my DAO's have to extend it and add new methods if needed, separately.

Then there is a shopDao class that all DAO's that are about shopping system extend this one.

An as an example, there is LanguageDao that should do transaction stuff on LanguageEntity.

Here is my code:

**abstractDao**

```
@Component
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public abstract class AbstractPgsqlDao<E> implements Dao<E> {
    protected EntityManager em;
    protected String entityClassName;

    protected void init(){
        entityClassName = this.getClass().getName().substring(this.getClass().getName().lastIndexOf(".")+1).trim().replace("Pgsql","").replace("Dao","Entity");
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }


    @Override
    public void insert(E entity) throws Exception {
            em.persist(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(E entity) {
        em.remove(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(long id) {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        String query = String.format("DELETE FROM %s table WHERE table.id= :id", entityClassName);
        Query jpaQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        jpaQuery.setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
        tx.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(E entity) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        em.merge(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public List selectAll() {
        String query = String.format("SELECT table FROM %s table ", entityClassName);
        Query jpaQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        List resultList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }

    @Override
    public List selectAll(String sort) {
        String query = String.format("SELECT table FROM %s table ORDER BY table." + sort, entityClassName);
        Query jpaQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        List resultList = jpaQuery.getResultList();
        return resultList;
    }

    @Override
    public E find(long id) {
        String query = String.format("SELECT table FROM %s table WHERE table.id = :id", entityClassName);
        Query jpaQuery = em.createQuery(query);
        jpaQuery.setParameter("id", Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(id)));
        E result = (E) jpaQuery.getSingleResult();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**AbstractShopPgsqlDao**

```
@Component
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class AbstractShopPgsqlDao<E> extends AbstractPgsqlDao<E> implements Dao<E> {
    public AbstractShopPgsqlDao() {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.em = entityManager;
    }
}
```

**PgsqlLanguageDao**

```
@Component
public class PgsqlLanguageDao extends AbstractShopPgsqlDao<LanguageEntity> implements LanguageDao {

}
```

**LanguageEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "language")
public class LanguageEntity {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String locale;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```

**mvc-dispatcher**

```
   <!-- This produces a container-managed EntityManagerFactory;
         rather than application-managed EntityManagerFactory as in case of LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean-->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!-- This makes /META-INF/persistence.xml is no longer necessary -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.easyshop.domain.entity"/>
        <!-- JpaVendorAdapter implementation for Hibernate EntityManager.
               Exposes Hibernate's persistence provider and EntityManager extension interface -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface,
            configuring the plain old JDBC DriverManager via bean properties -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/shop"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="pass"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- This transaction manager is appropriate for applications that use a single JPA EntityManagerFactory for transactional data access.
        JTA (usually through JtaTransactionManager) is necessary for accessing multiple transactional resources within the same transaction. -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryBean"/>
    </bean>
```

So I could insert some Languages into database but I can not update one.
I try

```
LanguageEntity languageEntity = languageDao.find(2);
System.out.println(languageEntity.getName());
languageEntity.setName("English");
languageEntity.setLocale("EN");
languageDao.update(languageEntity);
```

in my Controller but here is the error I get:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy193.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.easyshop.controller.HomeController.test2(HomeController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.easyshop.filter.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.easyshop.filter.BaseUrlFilter.doFilter(BaseUrlFilter.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:512)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.handlePostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.onPostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    ... 57 more
```

last root cause:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.handlePostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:71)
    org.hibernate.ejb.event.EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.onPostUpdate(EJB3PostUpdateEventListener.java:67)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:259)
    org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:206)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:395)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:387)
    org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:304)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349)
    org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:73)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerSynchronization.afterCommit(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:478)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.invokeAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:133)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerAfterCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:121)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:950)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:796)
    org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy498.update(Unknown Source)
    com.easyshop.controller.HomeController.test2(HomeController.java:48)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    com.easyshop.filter.DisableUrlSessionFilter.doFilter(DisableUrlSessionFilter.java:38)
    com.easyshop.filter.BaseUrlFilter.doFilter(BaseUrlFilter.java:27)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
```

I've searched around the internet, I tried rollbackFor parameteres for `@transactional` but did not work for me! can someone tell me whats wrong in the code?

plus, I cant start a transaction using `em.getTransaction()` (for sure `remove()` will not work) and I get `Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`. so how can I have active entitytransaction reference? how should I do commits or rollbacks?